# C# scan bluetooth LE devices

Tags: c#

I use C# to find Bluetooth Low Enegergy devices on Windows 10. When I run the following codes, I met such an error:

> "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code".

The line of the error is `Debug.WriteLine("Found device: " + devices[0].Id);`

I do not know why it is out of range. Thanks!

```
   namespace BluetoothLE
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private async void LookForPairedDevices()
            {

                // Get BLE devices paired with Windows
                DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelector());

                Debug.WriteLine("Found device: " + devices[0].Id);


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelector()` returned no devices, so trying to access index 0 (the first item) threw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is on this line:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Found device: " + devices[0].Id);
```

If you debug you're code, you'll see that `devices` has a length of 0 and you're trying to access the property `id` of the first one (which doesn't exist).

You may want to consider using a foreach loop to see what is returned like so:

```
foreach(var device in devices){
    Debug.WriteLine("Found device: " + device.Id);
}
```

Comment: If either of those were returning null you would get a null reference exception, not argument out of range. This error is about accessing more items than exist.

Comment: Thx for the explanation.